# Downloading Multiple Files through ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a setup where I need to download multiple files (at least 2) from a database where each file is stored as a binary array through ASP. I found an example from Microsoft that almost did the trick but I seem to be unable to download multiple files. It always downloads 1 file (even if there are 2) and then calls it "FullActivity" (which is the name of a Class I've made). Looks like this:

```
protected void download_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 id = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get(0));

    List<ActivityFile> files = Facade.GetActivityFiles(id);
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    if (files.Count == 0)
    {
        msg.Append("No files were found for this activity.");
        String jsExec = Util.ModalAlert(msg.ToString(), "#info_modal", ".modal-body");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "ModalAlertShow", jsExec, false);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (ActivityFile file in files)
        {
            //TODO: Perhaps find a dynamic way of doing this
            String folder = "\\\\jetfile01\\Users\\" + Util.GetUserAccount(this);
            switch (file.FileType)
            {
                case "pdf":
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                    break;
                case "docx":
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                    break;
                case "doc":
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                    break;
                case "xlsx":
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
                    break;
                case "xls":
                    Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
                    break;
                default:
                    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    break;
            }
            String filepath = MapPath(file.Name + "." + file.FileType);
            Response.BinaryWrite(file.FileBuffer);
            Response.Flush();
        }
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing and I don't know how I would actually name the file either. My ActivityFile class does contain the full name and extension of the file but I'm unsure on how to use this information in this scenario.

Any help?

Comment: One response object can only hold the bytes of one file. Use a .ZIP library like https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ to zip up all of the files into one .zip file.

Comment: n.b. My previous statement may not necessarily be true and it may indeed be achievable, but for simplicity, just create a zip file!

Answer (score 1):

Each file download is a response.

Each request can only have one response (apart from push notifications of course!)

Instead, render a page which either contains links, or makes seperate requests to download each file.

Or, download a zip archive containing multiple files.

[Edit]

I just thought about this a bit more and I'm no-longer convinced it's true!

It is how I'd probably do it though.

[/Edit]

IFRAME solution HTML

```
<iframe id='frame1' name='frame1' />
<iframe id='frame2' name='frame2' />
```

The script:

```
document.getElementById('frame1').src = 'downloadfile1.csv';
document.getElementById('frame2').src = 'downloadfile2.csv';
```

Comment: Well I tried what you suggested in terms of having multiple pages open, but it only ever opens the first page even though I start two threads to open multiple pages: http://pastebin.com/umXs8jK1 and then downloads that file.

Comment: I meant for you to make several download requests from a single page. Try making the calls 500ms apart so that your requests don't clash - could probably be less.

Comment: You probably won't like this, but maybe a better way is to use frames. Each frame could make its own request. You could call the script for each from your main page.

Comment: I am not sure how your frame solution would even work in this scenario.

Comment: I described it in the answer. From the server, your C# constructs a page with 2 `iframe` elements and a script to redirect each one to a separate download uri; except the MIME-type of the file will mean that the file is downloaded rather than loaded into the `iframe`.